# How to set gap tolerance in cplex-python?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, modeling, cplex

I want to set a gap value (GAP) such that the optimization process stops when the current gap will be lower than GAP. I have read the `cplex-python` documentation and I found that:

```
Model.parameters.mip.tolerances.absmipgap(GAP)
```

but I get the next warning:

```
Model.parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap(float(0.1))
TypeError: 'NumParameter' object is not callable
```

any ideas? please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using `docplex` or the CPLEX Python API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error you are getting, I think you might be using the CPLEX Python API rather than docplex (as in the other answers). To fix your problem, consider the following example:

```
import cplex                                                                    
Model = cplex.Cplex()                                                           
# This will raise a TypeError                                                   
#Model.parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap(float(0.1))                             
# This is the correct way to set the parameter                                  
Model.parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap.set(float(0.1))                          
# Write the parameter file to check that it looks as you expect                 
Model.parameters.write_file("test.prm")
```

You need to use the `set()` method. You can make sure that the parameter is changed as you expected by writing the parameter file to disk with the [write_file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._parameter_classes.RootParameterGroup-class.html) method and looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me adapt my bus example to your question:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')

# gap tolerance
mdl.parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap=0.001;


nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print("gap tolerance = ",mdl.parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap.get())
```

which gives:

```
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0
gap tolerance =  0.001
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is to call the parameter as if it was a function. The correct way to change a parameter is to assign to it:

```
Model.parameters.mip.tolerances.absmipgap = GAP
```

Also make sure that you don't use the `Model` class but an instance of this class:

```
mdl = Model()
mdl.parameters.mip.tolerances.absmipgap = GAP
```

Also be aware that there are two gap parameters: absolute and relative. The relative gap is the most frequently used. You can find the documentation for both [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpGap.html) and 
[here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpAGap.html) (the parameter for relative tolerance is called just `mipgap`).